# Copy Cell from an already open workbook to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code:

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
    Dim fromPath As String
    Dim toPath As String

    fromPath = InputBox(prompt:="Enter FROM File FULL Path:", _
    Title:="FROM FILE", Default:="")

    toPath = InputBox(prompt:="Enter TO File FULL Path:", _
    Title:="TO FILE", Default:="")

    Workbooks(fromPath).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F10").Copy
    Workbooks(toPath).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F10").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

I have 3 Workbooks (Macros.xlsm, CopyFrom.xlsx and CopyTo.xlsx). The above code is stored in Module 1 on the Macros.xlsm workbook.

Workbooks (CopyFrom.xlsx and CopyTo.xlsx) are already open...

What I need to do is: Copy value in cell (F10) from CopyFrom.xlsx workbook to cell (F10) in CopyTo.xlsx workbook...

I keep getting the following Error: "Subscript out of range"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the books are open, you don't need full path. Just book names.

Comment: I also tried with the book names but same error.

Comment: I assume you have "Sheet1". Hmm maybe try `worksheets` instead of `sheets` but uh why do you need to prompt for names if you already know which books they are? Edit: if you don't need formatting just set the ranges to each other instead of copy paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create objects for those workbooks.

```
Sub FillInternetForm()
    Dim fromPath As String
    Dim toPath As String
    Dim wbFrom As Workbook
    Dim wbTo As Workbook
    Dim fromValue As String

    fromPath = InputBox(prompt:="Enter FROM File FULL Path:", _
    Title:="FROM FILE", Default:="")

    toPath = InputBox(prompt:="Enter TO File FULL Path:", _
    Title:="TO FILE", Default:="")

    Set wbFrom = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fromPath, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wbTo = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=toPath, ReadOnly:=False)

    wbFrom.Activate
    fromValue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F10").Value

    wbTo.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F10").Value = fromValue

End Sub
```

I am not sure though why you say that they are already open and then you are asking for the full path to them. Maybe you can explain.

Comment: Oh so the parent is required to be an object as well. Good to know^^

Comment: @findwindow It is always best to declare any workbooks or worksheets. It prevents having to do .select or .activate. Gives you access to them without having to know they are active.

Comment: Wait, so the parent doesn't have to be set? I know it's good practice but talking technical here.

Comment: What do you mean by the parent? If you mean the modules workbook, it is active if the code is being run from there. I only declare what I am working with.

Comment: Workbook is parent of the range. Well, grandparent. (Worksheet is parent).

Comment: I specified the full path for both workbooks  (CopyFrom.xlsx and CopyTo.xlsx)  but I keep getting the same error on the following line:                  wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F10").Copy

Comment: Oh I think I see what you are asking.  I think, if a workbook is open, you can access anything in it by setting the object to any level of it, or you can access anything through it without . IE activeworkbook.sheets(1).Range("A1").Value without declaring anything.  I rarely do that though.  But I do access "children" through a declared object as I did in the answer.

Comment: @elyoe011 Did you make the change Workbooks(fromPath).Sheets to wbFrom.Sheets?

Comment: Thanks to you guys I was able to make a few edits and find the solution!! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: lol Matt wasted setting the books XD @elyoe011 try `fromValue = wbFrom.Sheets(1).Range("F10").Value`

Comment: Yeah, you could do that to :) That's what he ended up doing with the answer.